# How to import modules from adjacent package without setting PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

I have a python **2.7** project which I have structured as below:

```
project
    |
    |____src
    |       |
    |       |__pkg
    |           |
    |           |__ __init__.py
    |       
    |____test
            |
            |__test_pkg
            |       |
            |       |__ __init__.py
            |
            |__helpers
            |       |
            |       |__ __init__.py
            |
            |__ __init__.py
```

I am setting the `src` folder to the `PYTHONPATH`, so importing works nicely in the packages inside `src`. I am using eclipse, pylint inside eclipse and nosetests in eclipse as well as via bash and in a `make` file (for project). So I have to satisfy lets say every stakeholder!

The problem is importing some code from the helpers package in test. Weirdly enough, my test is also a python package with `__init__.py` containing some top level `setUp` and `tearDown` method for all tests. So when I try this:

```
import helpers
from helpers.blaaa import Blaaa
```

in some module inside `test_pkg`, all my stakeholders are not satisfied. I get the `ImportError: No module named ...` and pylint also complains about not finding it. I can live with pylint complaining in test folders but `nosetests` is also dying if I run it in the project directory and test directory. I would prefer not to do relative imports with dot (.).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you can not escape the current directory by importing from ..helpers.

But if you start your test code inside the test directory with

```
python3 -m test_pkg.foo
```

the current directory will be the test directory and importing helpers will work. On the minus side that means you have to import from . inside test_pkg.

Comment: Thanks...is that a python 3 solution since I am on 2.7 Sorry for the late info but I updated my question as well with the ver.

Comment: No, python 2.7 has -m too.